# Replace specific piece of code in node.js custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, fs

Let's say I have a module called 'pink.js'.
Inside that module is the following code:

```
var color = 'red+white'
module.exports = color
```

Now in another file, lets say we do the following:

```
const pink = require('./pink')
console.log(pink) //Logs 'red+white'
```

Then lets say we wanted to change the value of `color` in pink.js to `'red+blue'` by reqriting the file, and then re-requiring it.

```
const pink = require('./pink')
console.log(pink) //Logs 'red+white'

//Code to replace the value of color in pink.js to 'red+blue'

//Re-requiring:
const pink2 = require('./pink')
console.log(pink2) //Logs 'red+blue'
```

How would I go about doing this?

And if it is possible, could I do this to actual modules like `require.js`?

An example of how this could be used:
Patching simple problems in modules locally, by using code only. Maby to automate the process.

Thanks!

Comment: In first place, why do you need exactly to re-require it? In summary, whenever a values of a module changes, you're going to re-run your app and the values will be up-to-date. Other than this, if you need to communicate between 2 different modules, you should expose methods to do so. Can you ellaborate more on your needs?

Comment: @DiogoLessa It's not a need, its more of a "is-this-possible" kind of thing.

Comment: The answer is no. Once you require a file, it'll have the same value unless you modify and re-run your app. Thats why I am asking how you came up with this question. In general, each module has its own isolated scope. If the first module returns a string and didn't offer a method to change this, its only a readonly value. Only re-requiring wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @DiogoLessa Oh, alright. If you want to make that into an answer, I'll mark it as solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Once you require a file, it'll have the same value unless you modify and re-run your app. In general, each module has its own isolated scope. If the first module returns a string and didn't offer a method to change this, its only a readonly value. Only re-requiring wouldn't change anything.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
// Main.js
var Color = (module.exports = {
  value: 'red+white',
  changeColor: (newColor) => (Color.color = newColor),
})


// AnotherFile.js
var color = require('./main')

color.changeColor('red+blue')

console.log(color.value)
```